# Create a rainbow color meter to get color and values from user in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I want to create a digital rainbow meter in iOS. I want to get user response based on where user touch the rainbow in ios screen.

Digital rainbow meter is a VIBGYOR(voilet, indigo, blue, greeen, yellow, orange and red) gradient image, which is landscape image. If user touches the violet strip, i should be able to get the color in text form. 
And then i have to pass that color information to the MySQL database this part i have done by using php web service.

But i am not able to get the color of the user touch on image. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you divide the screen into seven strips, you can map each strip borders by checking their position. Then, if you override `touchesBegan`, you can perform the action you want.

Assuming that the rainbow is composed by horizontal strips, the touchesBegan method will look like this:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint touchLocation = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:touchView];
    if (touchLocation.y < violetDownBorder && touchLocation.y > violetUpBorder) {
        //Violet detected
        //... send @"Violet" string to wherever
    }else if (touchLocation.y < indigoDownBorder && touchLocation.y > indigoUpBorder){
        //....
        //Complete all colours (cases) here.
        //....
    }
}
```

Where `xxxxDownBorder` and `xxxxUpBorder` are the vertical position in pixels where the xxxx borders is placed.

Comment: Now the requirement is changed instead of striped we want a gradient of color we require a continuous gradient and then map that continuos gradient with the minimum and range. And when user touch anywhere in gradient, i want to get the color and get the values also where user touches the rainbow based on where he touched the screen in between the max and min range.